# How to optimize a join to a moderately large type II table on snowflake?

Tags: snowflake-cloud-data-platform

**Background**

Suppose I have the following tables:

```
-- 33M rows
CREATE TABLE lkp.session (
    session_id BIGINT,
    visitor_id BIGINT,
    session_datetime TIMESTAMP
);

-- 17M rows
CREATE TABLE lkp.visitor_customer_hist (
    visitor_id BIGINT,
    customer_id BIGINT,
    from_datetime TIMESTAMP,
    to_datetime TIMESTAMP
);
```

Visitor_customer_hist gives the customer_id that is in effect for each visitor at each point in time.

The goal is to look up the customer id that was in effect for each session, using the visitor_id and session_datetime.

```
CREATE TABLE lkp.session_effective_customer AS
    SELECT
        s.session_id,
        vch.customer_id AS effective_customer_id
    FROM lkp.session s
    JOIN lkp.visitor_customer_hist vch ON vch.visitor_id = s.visitor_id
        AND s.session_datetime >= vch.from_datetime
        AND s.session_datetime < vch.to_datetime;
```

**Problem**

Even with a warehouse scaled to large, this query is *extremely* slow.  It took 1h15m to complete, and it was the only query running on the warehouse.

I verified there are no overlapping values in visitor_customer_hist, the presence of which could cause a duplicative join.

Is snowflake just really bad at this kind of join?  I am looking for suggestions re how I might optimize the tables for this kind of query, re clustering, or any optimization technique or re-working of the query, e.g. maybe a correlated subquery or something.

**Additional info**

Profile:
[image: Profile]

Comment: That seems surprisingly long.  I wonder how many rows-per-visitor exist in visitor_customer_history -- maybe yielding join explosion.  For a clue, how long does it take to run the following (and what is the result)?

SELECT count(*)
    FROM lkp.session s
    JOIN lkp.visitor_customer_hist vch ON vch.visitor_id = s.visitor_id

Comment: I was hoping you'd see this one! Re join explosion, we can see from the insert that rows weren't duplicated by the join...  But 98% of visitors have <= 3 records, 1% have 4-10, and 1% have 10-10000.  Maybe something about the high-volume visitors causes trouble here.

Comment: I will try excluding visitors with more than 1000 records and see if it goes substantially faster...

Comment: This is definitely unexpected. I would contact Snowflake support, providing the exact query id, they can possibly help more.

Comment: Also, what @chorbs said might help - even if there are no overlapping values, the join is "fast" on visitor_id, as it's equality, and then "slow" on the time ranges. If e.g. there's 100,000 instances of the same visitor_id in both tables, that will cause a severe explosion inside the join.

Comment: So, I did try excluding the visitors that have many customers (and thus many records) and the query completed in a couple minutes. I got around this issue by writing a custom window function, obviating the need for this kind of join (some sessions are missing a customer id and we just need to find the next one for that visitor). But yeah something doesn't seem right and I will create a ticket with snowflake in case there is some kind of related bug.

Comment: But @MarcinZukowski why is there still join explosion even without overlapping values?  Does it have to first join all records based on equality condition and only subsequently filter based on the secondary conditions?  If so, it makes sense that it would be extremely slow and under certain cases, maybe not even complete!

Comment: @chorbs Yes, that's pretty much what happens. In most database systems the equality join is fast, and non-equality condition is slower. We could optimize it to be faster, alas, today within a single equality group it's like a cartesian product.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In cases where both tables have high record counts per-visitor, this join is problematic, for reasons Marcin described in the comments.  Accordingly, with this kind of scenario, it is best to **avoid this kind of join altogether** if possible.

The way I ultimately solved this issue was to **scrap the visitor_customer_hist table** and write a custom window function / udtf.

Initially I created `lkp.visitor_customer_hist` table because it could be created using existing window functions, and on a non-MPP sql database appropriate indexes could be created which would render lookups sufficiently performant.  It was created like so:

```
CREATE TABLE lkp.visitor_customer_hist AS
    SELECT
        a.visitor_id AS visitor_id,
        a.customer_id AS customer_id,
        nvl(lag(a.session_datetime) OVER ( PARTITION BY a.visitor_id
            ORDER BY a.session_datetime ), '1900-01-01') AS from_datetime,
        CASE WHEN lead(a.session_datetime) OVER ( PARTITION BY a.visitor_id
            ORDER BY a.session_datetime ) IS NULL THEN '9999-12-31'
        ELSE a.session_datetime END AS to_datetime
    FROM (
             SELECT
                 s.session_id,
                 vs.visitor_id,
                 customer_id,
                 row_number() OVER ( PARTITION BY vs.visitor_id, s.session_datetime
                     ORDER BY s.session_id ) AS rn,
                 lead(s.customer_id) OVER ( PARTITION BY vs.visitor_id
                     ORDER BY s.session_datetime ) AS next_cust_id,
                 session_datetime
             FROM "session" s
             JOIN "visitor_session" vs ON vs.session_id = s.session_id
             WHERE s.customer_id <> -2
         ) a
    WHERE (a.next_cust_id <> a.customer_id
        OR a.next_cust_id IS NULL) AND a.rn = 1;
```

So, **scrapping this approach**, I wrote the following UDTF insstead:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION udtf_eff_customer(customer_id FLOAT)
    RETURNS TABLE(effective_customer_id FLOAT)
LANGUAGE JAVASCRIPT
IMMUTABLE
AS '
{
    initialize: function() {
        this.customer_id = -1;
    },

    processRow: function (row, rowWriter, context) {
        if (row.CUSTOMER_ID != -1) {
            this.customer_id = row.CUSTOMER_ID;
        }
        rowWriter.writeRow({EFFECTIVE_CUSTOMER_ID:  this.customer_id});
    },

    finalize: function (rowWriter, context) {/*...*/},
}
';
```

And it can be applied like so:

```
SELECT
    iff(a.customer_id <> -1, a.customer_id, ec.effective_customer_id) AS customer_id,
    a.session_id
FROM "session" a
JOIN table(udtf_eff_customer(nvl2(a.visitor_id, a.customer_id, NULL) :: DOUBLE) OVER ( PARTITION BY a.visitor_id
    ORDER BY a.session_datetime DESC )) ec
```

So this accomplishes the desired result: for every session, if the customer_id is not "unknown", then we go ahead and use that; otherwise, we use the next customer_id (if one exists) that can be associated with that visitor (ordering by time of session).

This is a much better solution than creating the lookup table; it essentially takes only one pass at the data, requires a lot less code / complexity, and goes very fast.

Answer (score 2):

If the **lkp.session** table contains a *narrow* time range, and the **lkp.visitor_customer_hist** table contains a *wide* time range, you may benefit from rewriting the query to add a redundant condition restricting the range of rows considered in the join:

```
CREATE TABLE lkp.session_effective_customer AS
SELECT
    s.session_id,
    vch.customer_id AS effective_customer_id
FROM lkp.session s
JOIN lkp.visitor_customer_hist vch ON vch.visitor_id = s.visitor_id
    AND s.session_datetime >= vch.from_datetime
    AND s.session_datetime < vch.to_datetime
WHERE vch.to_datetime >= (select min(session_datetime) from lkp.session)
    AND  vch.from_datetime <= (select max(session_datetime) from lkp.session);
```

On the other hand, this won't help very much if both tables cover similar wide date range and there are large numbers of customers associated with a given visitor over time.

Answer (score 0):

Following [Stuart's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50634530/2761682), we can filter it a bit more by looking at the visitor-wise min and max.  Like so:

```
CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE _vch AS
    SELECT
        l.visitor_id,
        l.customer_id,
        l.from_datetime,
        l.to_datetime
    FROM (
             SELECT
                 l.visitor_id,
                 min(l.session_datetime) AS mindt,
                 max(l.session_datetime) AS maxdt
             FROM lkp.session l
             GROUP BY l.visitor_id
         ) a
    JOIN lkp.visitor_customer_hist l ON a.visitor_id = l.visitor_id
        AND l.from_datetime >= a.mindt
        AND l.to_datetime <= a.maxdt;
```

Then with our lighter-weight hist table, maybe we'll have better luck:

```
CREATE TABLE lkp.session_effective_customer AS
    SELECT
        s.session_id,
        vch.customer_id AS effective_customer_id
    FROM lkp.session s
    JOIN _vch vch ON vch.visitor_id = s.visitor_id
        AND s.session_local_datetime >= vch.from_datetime
        AND s.session_local_datetime < vch.to_datetime;
```

Unfortunately, in my case, though I filtered out a huge percentage of rows, the problem visitors (those with thousands of records in visitor_customer_hist) remained problematic (i.e. they still had thousands of records, resulting in join explosion).

In other circumstances, though, this could work.